# Invalid object name 'dbo.AspNetUserAspNetRoles'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, identity

Working with my first MVC5 project using entity framework.  When I load my users and attempt access the roles they are in, the lazy load is trying to load from AspNetUserAspNetRoles. The table is actually named AspNetUserRoles which I think is the default and is working fine when I am adding roles to a user.  My DBA setup the initial model collection for me and is away at a conference.  I think I am likely missing something in my DBContext, but after an hour I am still looking for a good reference to solve my issue.

Here is my AspNetUser model.  I eliminated a few of the other relationships to conserve space

```
    public partial class AspNetUser : IBusinessObject
{
    public AspNetUser()
    {
        this.AspNetRoles = new List<AspNetRole>();
    }

    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string PasswordHash { get; set; }
    public string SecurityStamp { get; set; }
    public string Discriminator { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime UpdatedOn { get; set; }
    public string CreatedByUserId { get; set; }
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
    public string ResetPasswordKey { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> ResetPasswordKeyExpiration { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<AspNetRole> AspNetRoles { get; set; }

    public void SoftDelete(bool reverse = false)
    {
        IsDeleted = !reverse;
    }

}
```

Here is the AspNetRole model

```
public partial class AspNetRole : INameable, IBusinessObject
{
    public AspNetRole()
    {
        this.AspNetUsers = new List<AspNetUser>();
    }

    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<AspNetUser> AspNetUsers { get; set; }

}
```

Here is my DbContext

```
public partial class SdContext : DbContext
    {
        static SdContext()
        {
            Database.SetInitializer<SdContext>(null);
        }

        public SdContext()
            : base("SdConnection")
        {
        }

        public DbSet<Cluster> Clusters { get; set; }
        public DbSet<CoLabDate> CoLabDates { get; set; }
        public DbSet<CoLabLocation> CoLabLocations { get; set; }
        public DbSet<CoLab> CoLabs { get; set; }
        public DbSet<CoLabType> CoLabTypes { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Document> Documents { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Organization> Organizations { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Participant> Participants { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Project> Projects { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Statement> Statements { get; set; }
        public DbSet<TriggeringQuestion> TriggeringQuestions { get; set; }
        public DbSet<VoteAction> VoteActions { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Vote> Votes { get; set; }
        public DbSet<VoteType> VoteTypes { get; set; }
        public DbSet<AspNetUser> AspNetUser { get; set; }
        public DbSet<AspNetRole> AspNetRole { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ClusterMap());
            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new CoLabDateMap());
            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new CoLabLocationMap());
            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new CoLabMap());
            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new CoLabTypeMap());
            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ContactMap());
            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new DocumentMap());
            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new OrganizationMap());
            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ParticipantMap());
            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ProjectMap());
            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new StatementMap());
            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new TriggeringQuestionMap());
            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new VoteActionMap());
            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new VoteMap());
            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new VoteTypeMap());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay...figured out what is probably the superior way to handle this.  I created a mapping file named AspNetRoleMap.cs

```
public AspNetRoleMap()
{
    // Primary Key
    this.HasKey(t => t.Id);

    // Properties
    // Table & Column Mappings
    this.ToTable("AspNetRoles");
    this.Property(t => t.Id).HasColumnName("Id");
    this.Property(t => t.Name).HasColumnName("Name");

    // Relationships
    this.HasMany(u => u.AspNetUsers)
        .WithMany(t => t.AspNetRoles)
        .Map(
            m =>
            {
                m.MapLeftKey("RoleId");
                m.MapRightKey("UserId");
                m.ToTable("AspNetUserRoles");
            }
        );

}
```

Then in the DbContext OnModelCreating() I added the below to include it.

```
modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new AspNetRoleMap());
```

Comment: Please edit your previos answer and post the whole solution there and remove this answer, to make it easier for others to understand what is the solution. And if it fixes your problem, mark your answer as accepted.

Comment: Instead I deleted the previous, since this is the whole solution.  I cannot flag it as accepted until it has been up 48 hours.